# AJAX Request Show Only One, but Controller called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i have problem with my Project. When i submit form, Ajax request only 1 in Developers Tool Mozilla but suddenly in Server As if the request called twice (i check with add log in the code). 
Sometimes this problem does not happen, but more happens.
Is it possible to related with stability internet connection?

Here is my ajax.

```
$('#GIForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        submitHandler:function(form){
            if(countSave == 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/new',
                    method:'post',
                    async: false,
                    data: {
                        date : $('#GIDate').val(),
                        notes : $('#GINotes').val(),
                        mswarehouse_id : $('#GISourceWarehouse').val(),
                        mstransactiontype_id : $('#GIType').val(),
                        dest_msoutlet_id : $('#GIOutlet').val(),
                        msvendor_id : $('#GIVendor').val(),
                        detail : detail
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
                        if(response.status=='success'){
                            var message = 'Document ' + response.description.document + ' has been saved!';
                            showAlert('',message,'success',function(e){
                                window.location.replace(laroute.route('admin.goods_issue.index'));
                            });
                        }else{
                            showAlert('',response.description,'error');
                            $('#addGIbtn').prop('disabled',false);
                            countSave = 0;
                        }
                    }, error:function(xhr,text, status){
                        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
                        $('#addGIbtn').prop('disabled',false);
                        countSave = 0;
                        if(xhr.status==422){
                            showAlert('',xhr.responseJSON.join('\n'),'error');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is picture from Dev. Tools Mozilla. I blur the domain. 
I don't know why the color status response only gray, and the response already give back status success. 
This problem make insert my database twice.
This is screenshot from my mozilla.
[Response from Network Dev Tools Mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyFGz.png)

Please help, I have no idea anymore

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan : he mention that his response status is success but strangely, his request / response don't have any status code like it's still waiting

Answer (score 0):

There is a `submitHandler` built into the plugin that contains something like `form.submit()`. Since you're .submit() with form that is not needed.So remove `$('#GIForm').submit(function(){})`.

```
 $('#GIForm').validate({
        submitHandler:function(form){
            if(countSave == 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/new',
                    method:'post',
                    async: false,
                    data: {
                        date : $('#GIDate').val(),
                        notes : $('#GINotes').val(),
                        mswarehouse_id : $('#GISourceWarehouse').val(),
                        mstransactiontype_id : $('#GIType').val(),
                        dest_msoutlet_id : $('#GIOutlet').val(),
                        msvendor_id : $('#GIVendor').val(),
                        detail : detail
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
                        if(response.status=='success'){
                            var message = 'Document ' + response.description.document + ' has been saved!';
                            showAlert('',message,'success',function(e){
                                window.location.replace(laroute.route('admin.goods_issue.index'));
                            });
                        }else{
                            showAlert('',response.description,'error');
                            $('#addGIbtn').prop('disabled',false);
                            countSave = 0;
                        }
                    }, error:function(xhr,text, status){
                        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
                        $('#addGIbtn').prop('disabled',false);
                        countSave = 0;
                        if(xhr.status==422){
                            showAlert('',xhr.responseJSON.join('\n'),'error');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope It Helps!